# IndexOf with InvariantCulture returning -1

Tags: c#, asp.net

Shouldn't the following code return 4? It is returning -1

```
string sa = "soy mas grande";
Response.Write("CMP: "+sa.IndexOf("más", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)+"<br>");
```

Comment: From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx): "DON'T Use `StringComparison.InvariantCulture`-based string operations in most cases; one of the few exceptions would be persisting linguistically meaningful but culturally-agnostic data." It does not look like this is one of the exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StringComparison.InvariantCulture` won't strip accents, you may be looking for this:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
      .CompareInfo.IndexOf(sa,
                           "más",
                           System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace)
```

Answer (score 2):

No; "más" is not "mas" so it isn't going to match.

Comment: I thought InvariantCulture would strip the accent

Comment: No; you need to look into removing accents from the string before comparing; see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net